# AbstractRoutingDataSource's getConnection is only called once per request

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to implement horizontal sharding using Spring Boot and JPA. Specifically I am using AbstractRoutingDataSource as explained here: http://fedulov.website/2015/10/14/dynamic-datasource-routing-with-spring/ and I have a working solution in case I do not switch datasources in the same http request context.

For instance I have this RestController method which works fine. Depending on the playerName, the correct datasource is selected for the request.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/players/register/{playerName}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String register(@PathVariable String playerName) {
    try {
        ShardingContext.setCurrentShardForPlayer(playerName);
        return playerService.registerPlayer(playerName);
    }
    finally {
        ShardingContext.clearShard();
    }
}
```

But when I try to run this method which tries to access players in different datasources in the same request, the second player cannot be found because the datasource switch does not take effect, the datasource in AbstractRoutingDataSource seems to be correctly selected but Spring cannot recognise it at that moment.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get/{player1}/{player2}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Player> getPlayers(@PathVariable String player1, @PathVariable String player2){

    try {
        ShardingContext.setCurrentShardForPlayer(player1);
        Player player1data = playerService.loadUserByUsername(player1);
        ShardingContext.setCurrentShardForPlayer(player2);
        Player player2data = playerService.loadUserByUsername(player2);
        return Arrays.asList(player1data, player2data);
    } finally {
        ShardingContext.clearShard();
    }
}
```

I would expect the data source switch takes effect (datasource's getConnection method should be called by Spring for this, I think) before starting the second transaction but it does not. How can I force Spring to call datasource's getConnection method before the second method call to playerService.loadUserByUsername() ?

The player service method is defined as follows:

```
    @Transactional( propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW )
public Player loadUserByUsername(String username) {
    Player player = playerRepository.findOneByName(username);
    return player;
}
```

The ShardingContext code:

```
    private static ThreadLocal<String> currentShard = new ThreadLocal<>();

public static void setCurrentShardForPlayer(String playerId) {
    int hashCode = playerId.hashCode();
    int shard = hashCode % numberOfShards;
    shard = ((shard+numberOfShards) % numberOfShards) + 1;
    currentShard.set(shard+"");
    log.info("Current shard set to {} - {} for player {}", shard, currentShard.get(), playerId);
}

public static void clearShard(){
    currentShard.remove();
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this ? I'm stuck a same kinda problem.

Comment: @AnkitSingodia No, actually we gave up the sharding approach.